# Is there a shorthand for returning conditional integer (error code) in C? That's kinda similar to Go

Tags: c, go

Is there a shorthand for returning conditional error code from a function in C? From something like:

```c
int e = 0; // Error code.
e = do_something()
if (e)
  return e;

// ...rest of the code when no error.
```

In Go, you can do like:

```golang
if err := doSomething(); err != nil {
  return err;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `errno.h`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error

Comment: You can write `if ((e = do_something()) != 0) { return e; }` but it is not necessarily the clearest; in particular the parentheses around `(e = do_something())` are easy to forget and the meaning will change if they are omitted.  Or you can use the comma operator: `if (e = do_something, e != 0) { ... }` but it is also maybe not ideally clear.

Comment: @NateEldredge That could work, but as I said in the other answer I wonder if it's possible to place the initializer inside parenthesis to limit the scope, like it does in Go.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with C++? Your title and body only refer to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using a macro for that particular case:

```
#define CHECK_SUCCESS(cmd) \
    do \
    { \
        int e = cmd; \
        if (0 != e) \
            return e; \
    } while (0);
```

Then any time you wanna check if your functions succeed:

```
CHECK_SUCCESS(do_something());
CHECK_SUCCESS(my_func(arg));
```

Comment: You're on the right track as I was going to suggest this. Just change to: `int e = cmd;` and remove the function scoped `int e` and you'll get the limited scope that OP wants.

Comment: ‘int e = cmd’ will be a problem if he wants to call that macro twice in the same function since it will be redeclared. This usage is great if you make it a convention to declare the ‘e’ variable at the start of each function.

Comment: No. You can use _many_: `#define CHECK_SUCCESS do { int e = cmd; if (0 != e) return e; } while (0)` OP does _not_ want `e` to persist, so you make it _block_ scoped--that's the whole point.

Comment: Ah yea forgot it’s a do while so it’s a different scope, yep fixed it :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not give it a try:

```
if ((e = do_something()) != 0) return e;

// ...rest of the code when no error.
```

This makes it one-lined but not so much clear to read. The operator precedence rule is applied here, so those parenthesis after `e` and before `0` are obviously necessary.

Comment: Nice, will work with c and c++ equally well.

Comment: I was hoping that this could work with the initializer inside the parenthesis like `if ((int e = do_something()) != 0) return e;` as I want the error code scope as small if possible.

Comment: @fullmoon6661 as mentioned in @super's answer, you need at least `std=c++17` to declare + compare in a single statement. [Look at the compiler](https://ibb.co/6r5NFvW) [demo of what happens if you don't use c++17]

Answer (score 2):

Since c++17 you can use init-statements in if's.

```
if (int e = do_something(); e != 0) {
    return e;
}

// ... rest
```

Comment: You don't even need the C++17 version since you just check for truthiness: `if (int e = do_something()) return e;` works fine in C++98.